# How to get the users who viewed a video on 95%?

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

There is a table with viewed chunks.

```
video_id | user_id | start_second | end_second 
    1    |     1   |       0      |    10
    1    |     1   |       0      |    20
    1    |     2   |       1      |    21
    1    |     3   |       0      |    10
    1    |     4   |      15      |    21
```

For example, video length is 21 sec. So, I'm expecting to get user 1 and user 2, but not user 3 or user 4

Comment: what rdms are you using?

Comment: I’m using MySql. Thanks.

Comment: You added a `gaps-and-islands` tag which implies that you're doing something with overlapping intervals.  In your sample data, though, you could simply take the `max(end_second)` for each user and see if that is 20.  Are your actual requirements more complicated than that?  Could a user start at 15 seconds and watch to second 21?  Would you want to count that (they got to 95%) or not (they didn't watch the first 15 seconds so they only really watched 6/21 ~= 29% of the video)?

Comment: @JustinCave  Yes, a user could skip a chunk of video and watched from 15 to 21. But it mean that 29% of video was watched.

Comment: I edited your question to add sample data for a user 4 that shows that you don't just want `max(end_second)`.  Please make sure that I haven't changed the intention of your question

Comment: Thank you, sir. It’s ok.

Comment: *I edited your question to add sample data for a user 4* Add more 2 users. One with 0-10 and 15-21 intervals, another with 0-15 and 10-21 intervals. As I understand second of them must be selected whereas the first do not. And specify MySQL version - it is important.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, may be

```
select video_id, user_id, max(end_second - start_second)
from vid
group by video_id, user_id
having cast(max(end_second - start_second) as float)/21. > .95
```

([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c55ebada36ef6213658a14312d52307c))

Comment: Wrong it seems. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4566c605593dd81acd45b69a428ce20c) - user 5 have seen the whole video moments but he is absent in output.

Comment: @Akina where's user 5 in the sample? The OP says it expects to see users 1 and 2.

Comment: OP gives EXAMPLE. I add one more user matched the condition - but your query rejected him. OP's sample data does not include all possible choices.

Comment: @Akina We don't know that the OP is asking for someone who viewed 95% of the video in one session or across multiple sessions. You are making the assumption that as long as all times viewing the video add up to 95% that is what matters. However it is much more complicated to exclude skipped or duplicate ranges in the calculation. Considering that is not a scenario that the op provided I don't think they care about it.

Comment: *in one session or across multiple sessions.* For one session the solution is too trivial for to ask it about I think. *We don't know that the OP is asking* Subj: **who viewed a video on 95%**. User 5 in my addition have seen more than 95% of the video. *exclude skipped or duplicate ranges* Ranges may overlap - so all overlapped ranges must be joined into one range.

Comment: @Akina you're welcome to post your version of an answer to your version of the question.

Comment: @mustaccio I'll wait until OP answers to my comment.

Comment: Shouldn't the 21 come from some table?

Comment: The `CAST()` will fail because it does not know about `FLOAT`.  I don't think any casting is necessary.